# How should the correct tests be?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing

I am searching to write correct and understandable tests on react. I have read a lot of articles and texts. But I haven't understood a few matters. I have a component which request with axios. So there are requests like GET, POST.

How should the backend behave during frontend testing? Should the backend switch to test mode after frontend tests started ? Should the database reset itself after each frontend test ?

I think I shouldn't mock API to check if component correct render. What is the correct logic ?

Answer (score 1):

The way that I approach this will be to mock the API call, the reason to do that will be, that I am reducing my scope of testing, As I am testing the React part, I would mock the success response and mock the error response and check how my components are working.

For the API testing, I will create a separate test case on the backend side. This way there will separation of concern. That is when I am testing react side I limit myself to the react side only and also this will make your test run fast as you are mocking the response, the actual request will not be sent and so you will get the response quickly.